# Angular, PrimeNg value p-message is not allowed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeicons

Hello got some problem with the p-message Tag in angular. I think ive imported it correctly as i show below.

```
  import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';

  imports: [
    ....
    MessageModule,
    ...
```

In the html component it is:

```
  <p-message [value]="message"></p-message>
```

And in addition, in the ts script it is:

```
  message: Message[] = [];
```

Why i got this error, all the time?!

1. If 'p-message' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-message' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

I want to display the error toastmessage above the inputfield, that someone knows that it already exists.

Thanks in the front for your help guys!

Comment: which version of primeng?

Comment: If it's your feature module then you have to add messageModule to that feature module too!

Comment: im using angular 13.1.0

Comment: it is already in the feature module

Comment: It works now with <p-messages [(value)]="message"></p-messages> but the message is just always shown in the back of the dialog.. i want it in the modal window!

Comment: can you post some screenshots of what is happening?

Comment: post your modal code. you probably need to add  your modal component to entryComponents or add it's module to imports

Comment: its working, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

p-message only accepts the following parameters - This is to show inline message of any form element

[image]

Inorder to show any alert messages you have to use p-messages with value (Message[]) or using the MessageService
[image]

Makesure you have imported MessagesModule or MessageModule based on your requirement.

If planning to use MessageService, make sure to import in the Providers

Answer (score 0):

For other that maybe has the same problem. I was initially confused because there are two similarly named modules: **MessageModule** and **MessagesModule**.

```
<p-message severity="error" text="Field is required"></p-message>

<p-messages [(value)]="messages2" [enableService]="false"></p-messages>
```